# asymptotic behavior of the two sequences defining exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

There are two definitions of exponential function: $$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n \text{       ,}$$ where $$S_n=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots+\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ and $$a_n=(1+\frac{x}{n})^n \text{   .}$$

Since the two sequence have the same limit, I guess they are somehow related and reflect different aspects of $e^x$. So my first question is: are there any relationships between $S_n$ and $a_n$?

My other questions come from the following observations:

When x is positive, obviously $S_n$ is increasing. Is $a_n$ also increasing?

When x is negative, $S_n$ goes up and down since it keeps adding numbers of alternating signs as as $n$ grows. Eventually $S_n$ "squeezes" to its limit. What about the behavior of $a_n$ in this case? When $n$ is smaller than $|x|$, I can see that $a_n$ changes signs very often. When $n$ is large, $a_n$ is always positive, and is $a_n$ increasing when $n$ is large?

Comment: Have you looked at the binomial expansion of $a_n$?

Comment: $\displaystyle \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n =\displaystyle 1 + {n \choose 1}\frac{x}{n}+{n \choose 2}\frac{x^2}{n^2}+{n \choose 3}\frac{x^3}{n^3}+\cdots \to 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots $ as $n$ increases

Comment: @Henry: That limit is problematic since it contains a moving target in the number of terms in the binomial expansion. You would need something like uniform convergence to get the limit in the coefficients commuted with the series limit.

Comment: @LutzL: TO me, what matters is each term $\displaystyle {n \choose k}\dfrac{x^k}{n^k}$ in the binomial expansion (using $0$ if $n \lt k$) is smaller in magnitude than the corresponding term $\dfrac{x^k}{n!}$  in the exponential series and the exponential series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Yes, that should also do nicely. Question remains if that fact is already known at the current point of the course.

Comment: Note that $S_n$ converges MUCH faster than $a_n$ (which converges at $O(\frac 1 n)$ relative rate).

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial formula: 
$$
\left(1+\dfrac{x}{n} \right)^n  =1+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{x^k}{n^k}
$$
where the coefficient of $x^k$ is:
$$
\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!\,n^k}=\dfrac {1}{k!} \, \dfrac{1\times 2 \times 3 \cdots \times n}{[1\times 2  \cdots \times (n-k)]\,\times \,\underbrace {n\times n \cdots \times n}_{k \,\mbox{times}}}
$$
that can be simplified as:
$$
\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!\,n^k}= \dfrac {1}{k!} \,\dfrac{\overbrace{(n-k+1)\times(n-k+ 2) \cdots \times (n-1)}^{(k-1)\,\mbox{factors}}}{\underbrace {n\times n \cdots \times n}_{(k-1) \,\mbox{factors}}}=
$$
$$
=\dfrac {1}{k!} \left[ \dfrac{(n-k+1)}{n}\times \dfrac{(n-k+ 2)}{n} \cdots \times \dfrac{(n-1)}{n}\right]=
$$
$$
=\dfrac {1}{k!}\,\left(1-\dfrac{k-1}{n}\right)\,\left(1-\dfrac{k-2}{n}\right)\cdots\,\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)
$$

now, for $n \to \infty$ all the factors in the parenthesis $\to 1$ so we have:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!n^k}=\dfrac{1}{k!}
$$
and:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\dfrac{a}{n} \right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[1+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\dfrac{a^k}{n^k}\right] 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x > 0$ then it can be easily proven using binomial theorem (for positive integer index) that
\begin{align}
\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n} &= 1 + x + \dfrac{1 - \dfrac{1}{n}}{2!}\cdot x^{2} + \dfrac{\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 - \dfrac{2}{n}\right)}{3!}\cdot x^{3} + \cdots\notag\\
&\leq 1 + x + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{x^{n}}{n!}\notag
\end{align}
and therefore $a_{n} \leq S_{n}$. Moreover from the expansion of $a_{n}$ (via binomial theorem above) you can see that as $n$ increases each term in the expansion increases as well as the number of terms also increases. Thus $a_{n}$ is an increasing sequence if $x > 0$.

The story of $a_{n}$ and $S_{n}$ is not complete without the introduction of another sequence $b_{n}$ defined by $$b_{n} = \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}$$ For $0 < x < n$ we can use the general binomial theorem (for any index) to get $$b_{n} = \left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n} = 1 + x + \dfrac{1 + \dfrac{1}{n}}{2!}\cdot x^{2} + \dfrac{\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{n}\right)\left(1 + \dfrac{2}{n}\right)}{3!}\cdot x^{3} + \cdots$$ and this shows clearly that for $0 < x < n$ we have $$a_{n} \leq S_{n} \leq b_{n}$$ It is easy to prove that $S_{n}$ represents a convergent series and since $a_{n}$ is increasing it follows that $a_{n}$ also is convergent for $x > 0$. Let $S_{n} \to S(x)$ and $a_{n} \to a(x)$. Note also that $b_{n}$ is decreasing sequence for $0 < x < n$ and is bounded below by $S(x)$ and hence $b_{n}$ also is convergent and let $b_{n} \to b(x)$. We then have $a(x) \leq S_{x} \leq b(x)$. The magic happens when we see that $a_{n}/b_{n} = (1 - x^{2}/n^{2})^{n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$ so that $a(x) = b(x)$ and therefore all the sequences $a_{n}, b_{n}, S_{n}$ tend to the same limit which is traditionally denoted by $e^{x}$.

To handle negative values of $x$ note that the limit $S(x)$ of $S_{n}$ is an infinite convergent series which has the interesting property that $S(x + y) = S(x)S(y)$ (this is proved via multiplication of series). It thus means that $S(-x) = 1/S(x)$. Note that the sequence $a_{n}, b_{n}$ are such that $b_{n}(x) = 1/a_{n}(-x)$ (added $x$ to show the dependence of $x$) and hence it follows that $b(x) = 1/a(-x)$ or $a(-x) = 1/a(x)$ and this establishes the relation $a(x) = b(x) = S(x)$ for negative values of $x$ also.

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$
E(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
We know that this power series has infinite radius of convergence and is thus a continuous (and differentiable, etc.) function.
By careful but elementary application  of the Cauchy product an binomial theorem one finds
$$
E(x)·E(y)=E(x+y)
$$
which as functional equation has the solution
$$
E(x)=E(1)^x=e^x
$$

---

By multiplying out
$$
\left(1+\frac xn\right)\left(1+\frac yn\right)\left(1-\frac {x+y}n\right)=1-\frac {x^2+xy+y^2}{n^2}-\frac {xy(x+y)}{n^3}
$$
one finds that for $e(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ it holds that
$$
e(x)e(y)e(-x-y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\left(1+\frac yn\right)^n\left(1-\frac {x+y}n\right)^n=1
$$
which again implies the functional equation 
$$
e(x)e(y)=e(x+y)
$$
For the Cauchy functional equation one would need to establish for instance continuity at $x=0$ to then again arrive at
$$
e(x)=e(1)^x=e^x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Following the outline given by Henry in the comments to the question:

---

**Proposition:** If $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(t)$ is a series with parameter $t$ so that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(0)$ converges absolutely, $|a_k(t)|\le|a_k(0)|$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}a_k(t)=a_k(0)$, then
$$
\lim_{t\to 0}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(0)
$$

---

**Proof:** Let $ε>0$ be arbitrary. Determine $N$ such that $\sum_{k=N}^\infty |a_k(0)|<ε/3$. Then select $\bar t$ such that $\sup_{k=0,…,N-1}|a_k(t)-a_k(0)|<ε/(3N)$ for all $t\in(0,\bar t)$. Then
$$
\left|\lim_{t\to 0}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(t)-\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(0)\right|\le\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}|a_k(t)-a_k(0)|+ \sum_{k=N}^\infty |a_k(t)|+\sum_{k=N}^\infty |a_k(0)|<ε.
$$

---

**Application:** Write the binomial theorem as
$$
\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac xn\right)^k
=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)…\left(1-\frac{k-1}n\right)\frac{x^k}{k!}
$$
thus using $a_k(t)=(1-t)(1-2t)…(1-(k-1)t)\frac{x^k}{k!}$ the assumption of above proposition are satisfied, which establishes pointwise convergence of $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ towards the value of the exponential series.